# Some images load after the page has fully loaded

Tags: html

I have this problem where, when I scroll down on other images on my website, they are white but then the image shows after a split second.

And I have been looking around to find something to fix it, but no luck.

My website is: https://lukasstauersboel.dk/

The first image load fine because of the preloader I have, but the other images don't really do.

The code I have:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

  <!-- Meta -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta class="foundation-mq">
  <meta property="og:title" content="Lukas Stauersbøl"/>
  <meta property="og:type" content="portfolio"/>
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://lukasstauersboel.dk/"/>

  <!-- Title w/icon -->
  <title>Lukas Stauersb&oslashl</title>

  <!-- Links -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/foundation.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/LineIcons.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="js/nav.js"></script>
  <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
  <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-/Gm+ur33q/W+9ANGYwB2Q4V0ZWApToOzRuA8md/1p9xMMxpqnlguMvk8QuEFWA1B" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.js"></script>
  <script src="js/parallax.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/parallax.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <script src="js/vendor/foundation.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
  <script src="js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="preloader-wrap">
    <div class="preload"></div>
  </div>
  <header>
    <!-- Nav bar -->
    <div id="navDiv">
      <ul id="topNav" class="topNavMain">
        <li class="topNavTrigger">
          <a class="icon icon-menu"><span>Menu</span></a>
            <nav class="topNavWrap">
              <div class="topNavScroll">
                <ul class="topNav">
                  <li>
                    <a class="icon lni-user" href="#aboutMe">About me</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="icon lni-book" href="#myKnowledge">My knowlegde</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="icon lni-envelope" href="#contactMe">Contact me</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </li>
        <li><a href="#">Lukas Stauersb&oslashl</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
      <!-- Nav bar end -->
  </header>

  <main>
    <div data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/bg1.jpg" class="parallax">
    <!-- Intro start -->
      <section id="introMsg" class="sectionPadding">
        <div class="grid-x">
          <div class="cell">
            <h1 class="welcomeMsg">Hello. <br> I'm Lukas Stauersb&oslashl.</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="cell">
            <p class="underWelcomeMsg">If you want to read more about me and what I can do, <br> then feel free to look around. </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
      <!-- Intro end -->
      <!-- About me start -->
      <section id="aboutMe" class="sectionBg">
        <div class="grid-x">
          <div class="cell small-12 medium-6 slideInLeft margin-fix">
            <h2 class="sectionTitle">About me</h2>
            <p class="sectionTxt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br> Fusce mollis pretium felis id ultricies. Sed libero risus, volutpat vel rhoncus et, auctor non ipsum. <br> Praesent sollicitudin nibh nisl, et sagittis nulla ornare at.</p>
          </div>
            <div class="cell small-12 medium-6 slideInRight">
              <img src="img/portrait.jpg" alt="" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/portrait.jpg" class="imgPortrait"></img>
            </div>
          </div>
      </section>
      <!-- About me end -->
      <!-- My work start -->
      <section>
        <div data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/bg2.jpg" class="parallax2">
      </section>
      <section id="myWork" class="sectionBg">
        <div class="grid-x">
          <div class="cell small-12 medium-6 slideInLeft margin-fix">
            <h2 class="sectionTitle">My work</h2>
            <p class="sectionTxt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br> Fusce mollis pretium felis id ultricies. Sed libero risus, volutpat vel rhoncus et, auctor non ipsum. <br> Praesent sollicitudin nibh nisl, et sagittis nulla ornare at.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="cell small-12 medium-6 slideInRight margin-fix">
            <h3 class="sectionTitle">Links</h3>
            <p class="sectionTxt">FreeCodeCamp projects: <a href="https://codepen.io/collection/nZKkRj/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">Click here</a>.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
      <!-- My work end -->
      <!-- My knowlegde start -->
      <section>
        <div data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/bg3.jpg" class="parallax2">
      </section>
        <section id="myKnowledge" class="sectionBg">
            <div class="grid-x">
              <div class="cell small-12 medium-6 margin-fix slideInLeft">
                <h2 class="sectionTitle">My knowlegde</h2>
                <p class="sectionTxt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br> Fusce mollis pretium felis id ultricies. Sed libero risus, volutpat vel rhoncus et, auctor non ipsum. <br> Praesent sollicitudin nibh nisl, et sagittis nulla ornare at.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="cell small-12 medium-6 margin-fix slideInBottom">
              </div>
            </div>
        </section>
      </div>
      <!-- My knowlegde end -->
      <!-- Contact me start -->
      <section>
        <div data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/bg4.jpg" class="parallax3">
      </section>
      <section id="contactMe" class="sectionBg">
        <div class="grid-x">
          <div class="cell small-12 medium-6 margin-fix2 slideInLeft">
            <form class="form-contact" method="POST">
              <h2 class="sectionTitle">Contact Me</h2>
              <label for="inputName" class="sr-only">Name:</label>
              <input type="name" name="name" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" required>
              <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">E-Mail:</label>
              <input type="email" style="margin: 0 0 1rem;" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="i.e (johndoe@gmail.com)" required>
              <label for="inputSubject" class="sr-only">Subject:</label>
              <input type="name" name="subject" id="inputSubject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject..." required>
              <label for="inputMsg" class="sr-only">Message:</label>
              <textarea name="message" class="form-control box-size" id="inputMsg" rows="5" placeholder="Type you message..." required></textarea>
              <button class="button secondary" type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>
          </div>
                    <div class="cell small-12 medium-6 slideInRight margin-fix3 center-fix">
            <h3 class="sectionTitle padding-bottom">Social Media</h3>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/lukasstauersboel" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" class="button lni lni-facebook-original size-sm">Facebook</a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/lukas-stauersb%C3%B8l/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" class="button lni lni-linkedin-original size-sm">LinkedIn</a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/lukas_stauersbol/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" class="button lni lni-instagram-original size-sm">Instagram</a>
                    </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <section id="bottomPage" class="sectionBg4">
        <div class="center-fix copyright">
          &copy; <?php
          $fromYear = 2019;
          $thisYear = (int)date('Y');
          echo $fromYear . (($fromYear != $thisYear) ? '-' . $thisYear : '');?> Lukas Stauersb&oslashl.
        </div>
    </section>
  </footer>

  <script>
    new sMenu( document.getElementById( 'topNav' ) );
  </script>

  <script>
  var slideInLeft = {
    distance: '100%',
    origin: 'left',
    duration: 600,
    opacity: null
  };

  var slideInRight = {
    distance: '100%',
    origin: 'right',
    duration: 750,
    opacity: null
  };

  var slideInTop = {
    distance: '150%',
    origin: 'top',
    duration: 650,
    opacity: null
  };

  var slideInBottom = {
    distance: '100%',
    origin: 'bottom',
    duration: 690,
    opacity: null
  };

  ScrollReveal().reveal('.slideInBotttom', slideInBottom);
  ScrollReveal().reveal('.slideInTop', slideInTop);
  ScrollReveal().reveal('.slideInLeft', slideInLeft);
  ScrollReveal().reveal('.slideInRight', slideInRight);
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function parseJSAtOnload() {
    var links = ["js/nav.js", "js/classie.js", "js/scripts.js", "js/parallax.js", "js/modernizr.custom.js", "js/parallax.min.js", "js/vendor/what-input.js", "js/vendor/foundation.js", "js/vendor/foundation.min.js"],
    headElement = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
    linkElement, i;
    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      linkElement = document.createElement("script");
      linkElement.src = links[i];
      headElement.appendChild(linkElement);
    }
  }
  if (window.addEventListener)
  window.addEventListener("load", parseJSAtOnload, false);
  else if (window.attachEvent)
  window.attachEvent("onload", parseJSAtOnload);
  else window.onload = parseJSAtOnload;
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parallax-mirror divs have a css attribute `visibility: hidden` until the very last moment the related data-parallax div appears on screen. Then it receives a `visibility: visible` and that explain the flicker.

It works great on the library example website because their images are 1400px wide, while yours are 4800px wide (depending on the image). You should consider resizing your images to more suitable sizes and weights for the web. IMO 1200px is a good compromise between image quality and load speed accross any viewport and device.

Comment: Okay. I will try that too see if there is gonna be any change. I will get back to you.

Comment: it worked smoothly with the resizing. Thanks for the tip. I will use it.